# A column named [column name] already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: .net, t-sql, datatable, dotnetnuke

```
private void BindFields()
{
    DataTable table = Globals.ConvertDataReaderToDataTable(DataProvider.GetFields());
    _fieldCount = table.Rows.Count;

    dataGrid.DataSource = table;
    dataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

The ConvertDataReaderToDataTable, provided by the DotNetNuke platform, throws this exception :

> A column named [column name] already belongs to this DataTable

I do have columns with the same names in different tables, but they are primary/foreign key pairs and thus have the same values. What would you do to solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder why they don't just use myDataTableInstance.Load(myDataReaderInstance)

Comment: Seems to have solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

instead of DotNetNuke's

```
DataTable dataTable = Globals.ConvertDataReaderToDataTable(dataReader);
```

and I don't get the exception anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have the same column selected in your SQL JOIN Statements. I fixed this problem by removing the the duplicate column from my sql join like this

Change This

```
    SELECT O.Section,S.CurriculumTblCode, 
    S.Section ,S.SectionSettingTblCode FROM 
    otf.ViewOneToFiveGroups O 
    INNER JOIN 
    SectionSetting S ON O.SectionSettingTblCode= S.SectionSettingTblCode`
```

To this, Just by removing the duplicate **S.Section**

```
     SELECT O.Section,S.CurriculumTblCode,S.SectionSettingTblCode 
     FROM 
     otf.ViewOneToFiveGroups O 
     INNER JOIN SectionSetting S ON O.SectionSettingTblCode= 
     S.SectionSettingTblCode
```

Comment: it's helpful for me when i use flat file import through SSMS.

Answer (score -1):

You would typically only use one of the columns in the data source. Short of that, you would alias one of the other columns.

Using only one of the duplicates

```
Select a.SomeColumn, b.OtherStuff
From TableA a
Inner Join TableB b
on a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn
```

Or using an alias

```
Select a.SomeColumn, b.SomeColumn as SomeColumnB, b.OtherStuff
From TableA a
Inner Join TableB b
on a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn
```